# how to send the list of different class in Dictionary array in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a project in C# MVC.net.

I have two lists in the controller

```
List<layouts> L1 = (List<layouts>)result.Data;
List<SeatPlans>[] allUser = new List<SeatPlans>[10];
```

and I am sending the allUser list to ajax as follows

```
var v = new Dictionary<String, List<SeatPlans>>();

int i;
for (i=0; i < L1.Count; i++)
{
    int k = i - 1;
    v.Add($"all{i}", allUser[i]);
    // id++;
}

return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and this much is working fine. What I need is, have to send the List L1 also with allUser. How can I do this?
<sub>*allUser is lists of SeatPlans class and L1 
is the list of layouts class*</sub>

Comment: Why are you using a `Dictionary` - just send the data using `return Json(new { L1 = L1, allUser = allUser }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and then you have both collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this.

Send a JsonResult back and create an instance in your controller:

```
public JsonResult Action() {
    var json = new JsonResult();

    json.Body = new {
        List1 = L1, Dictionary = v
    };

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create a class with two properties, one for each list

```
public class MyData
{
    public List<layouts> Layouts{get; set;}
    public List<SeatPlans> SeatPlans{get; set;}
}
```

and return an instance of that:

```
return new MyData
{
    Layouts = L1,
    SeatPlans = allUser
};
```

in fact, you can actually avoid writing the definition for the class and return an anonymous type:

```
return new
{
    Layouts = L1,
    SeatPlans = allUser
};
```

Comment: how can i process the returned data in ajax success function

Comment: @rakshi, assuming you have `success: function(data) {` then its just `$.each(data.Layouts, function(index, item) {` to loop though the first collection (ditto for `$.each(data.SeatPlans , function(index, item) {`)